# JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "RCTWebSocketModule"

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, react-native

I have upgraded react and react-native dependencies. When I try to build and run my react-native application on a real device, I get following stacktraces in xcode and app freezes on a white screen after launching.

```
2016-10-04 12:33:37.501 [info][tid:main][RCTBatchedBridge.m:74]   Initializing <RCTBatchedBridge: 0x16575a10> (parent: <RCTBridge:   0x1658e200>, executor: RCTJSCExecutor)
2016-10-04 12:33:37.507136 ReactApp[237:7244] Initializing <RCTBatchedBridge: 0x16575a10> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x1658e200>, executor: RCTJSCExecutor)
2016-10-04 12:33:37.695956 ReactApp[237:7292] [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 1 Connection has no connected handler
2016-10-04 12:33:37.780 [info][tid:main][RCTBatchedBridge.m:74] Initializing <RCTBatchedBridge: 0x16681ec0> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x1658e200>, executor: RCTWebSocketExecutor)
2016-10-04 12:33:37.780715 ReactApp[237:7244] Initializing <RCTBatchedBridge: 0x16681ec0> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x1658e200>, executor: RCTWebSocketExecutor)
2016-10-04 12:33:37.865 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.RCTBridgeQueue][RCTModuleData.mm:287] Required dispatch_sync to load constants for RCTUIManager. This may lead to deadlocks
2016-10-04 12:33:37.866815 ReactApp[237:7292] Required dispatch_sync to load constants for RCTUIManager. This may lead to deadlocks
2016-10-04 12:33:38.274 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "RCTWebSocketModule"
2016-10-04 12:33:38.274231 ReactApp[237:7303] JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "RCTWebSocketModule"
2016-10-04 12:33:38.281 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] 'Failed to print error: ', 'JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "RCTSourceCode"'
2016-10-04 12:33:38.281396 ReactApp[237:7303] 'Failed to print error: ', 'JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "RCTSourceCode"'
2016-10-04 12:33:38.286 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Requiring module "185", which threw an exception.
2016-10-04 12:33:38.286470 ReactApp[237:7303] Requiring module "185", which threw an exception.
2016-10-04 12:33:38.287 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] 'Failed to print error: ', 'Requiring module "191", which threw an exception.'
2016-10-04 12:33:38.286985 ReactApp[237:7303] 'Failed to print error: ', 'Requiring module "191", which threw an exception.'
```

When I run same project with android studio, I get following stacktraces:

```
E/ReactNativeJS: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "UIManager"
I/ReactNativeJS: 'Failed to print error: ', 'JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "SourceCode"'
W/unknown:React: Packager connection already open, nooping.
E/ReactNativeJS: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module.
E/ReactNativeJS: Requiring module "173", which threw an exception.
I/ReactNativeJS: 'Failed to print error: ', 'Requiring module "173", which threw an exception.'
I/ReactNativeJS: 'Failed to print error: ', 'JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "ExceptionsManager"'
```

Package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "15.3.2",
    "react-native": "^0.34.1",
    "react-native-animatable": "0.6.1",
    "react-native-collapsible": "0.7.0",
    "react-native-drawer": "2.2.6",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-viewpager": "0.2.11",
    "react-redux": "4.4.5",
    "redux": "3.5.2",
    "redux-thunk": "2.1.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this tonight. It was a cache issue for me. Restart the React Native Packager.

Answer (score 0):

the package.json is not valide. Here a response from json-validator:

`Error: Parse error on line 1:
"dependencies": {
    "react": "1
--------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'`

It must look like this:

`{
"dependencies": {
    "react": "15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "15.3.2",
    "react-native": "^0.34.1",
    "react-native-animatable": "0.6.1",
    "react-native-collapsible": "0.7.0",
    "react-native-drawer": "2.2.6",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-viewpager": "0.2.11",
    "react-redux": "4.4.5",
    "redux": "3.5.2",
    "redux-thunk": "2.1.0"
  }
}`

Comment: I have added just a dependency snippet of the Package.json. That's not the cause behind the error. I have a valid json in Package.json

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when integrating with existing apps. I solved it. My "react-native" version code in `package.json` was not same as the Android app's. I used npm to install the same version.